# Deep Security Management Console

Tags: deepsecurity

asked DSM and solved Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this list for Deep Security system requirements, including the browsers supported for connecting to the DSM console: https://help.deepsecurity.trendmicro.com/12_0/on-premise/Get-Started/Install/system-requirements.html#Deep

P.S. I work for Trend Micro in R&D